# Problemas al hacer deply en render

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, docker

Estoy intentando hacer un deploy en render con Clever cloud y docker file.Alguien que tenga experiencia me podria decir cual es el problema , es que no me dice ningun error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde aparece el Failed , te muestra un mensaje diciendo en proceso y va compilando el proyecto hasta que termina de compilarse y en la consola aparece el tipico mensaje de

> INFO 1 --- [           main] c.b.ClinicaOdontologicaApplication
> : Started ClinicaOdontologicaApplication in 121.99 seconds (process
> running for 130.515)

Y despues de eso me aparece estos mensajes en la consola :

> ==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys

> 2024-03-18T22:31:48.266Z  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

> 2024-03-18T22:31:48.358Z  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
> initiated...

> 2024-03-18T22:31:48.456Z  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
> completed.

Despues compila una 3 veces mas y termina ahi...de la nada me aparece un FAILED

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo ultimo que me aparece